# Nice form for determinant of a special matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have a positive definite symmetric matrix that looks like

[image]

where matrices $A,B,C,D$ are positive definite symmetric matrices. Is there a nice way to calculate the determinant? For example, the upper left block is block diagonal and its determinant is just $\det(A)\cdot\det(B)$.

I want to find the determinant of the whole matrix though.

I have provided an example of such matrix using dput in `R`. You just need to copy and paste to `R` for a reproducible example

Comment: Do the row operations and keep track of the scalings you get. The form is quite nice.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement

Answer (score 1):

Using the Schur complement, your determinant is
$$
\det(A)\det(B)\det(C)\det\big(D - E'A^{-1}E - F'B^{-1}F - G'C^{-1}G\big).
$$
Does this help?